Python typing Protocol with default
I have a simple function which simply executes a callback:
def callback(*, arg1: float | None = None) -> float:
    return arg1 or 1.0

def callback2(*, arg1: int | None = None) -> int:
    return arg1 or 1

def func(arg1 = callback, arg2 = None):
    return arg1(arg1=arg2)

func(callback)
func(callback2)

For these callback functions arg1 and the return type are always the same type and can be either int or float.
My first attempt without a default for the scorer was
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar, Protocol

_ResultType = TypeVar("_ResultType", int, float)
_ContraResultType = TypeVar("_ContraResultType", int, float, contravariant=True)
_CoResultType = TypeVar("_CoResultType", int, float, covariant=True)

class MyCallback(Protocol[_ContraResultType, _CoResultType]):
    def __call__(self, *, arg1: _ContraResultType | None) -> _CoResultType: ...

def callback(arg1: float | None = None) -> float:
    return arg1 or 1.0

def callback2(arg1: int | None = None) -> int:
    return arg1 or 1

def func(
    arg1: MyCallback[_ResultType, _ResultType],
    arg2: _ResultType | None = None,
) -> _ResultType:
    return arg1(arg1=arg2)

a: float = func(callback)
b: int = func(callback2)

which appears to work. However if I update the implementation to include the default in the following way:
def func(
    arg1: MyCallback[_ResultType, _ResultType] = callback,
    arg2: _ResultType | None = None,
) -> _ResultType:
    return arg1(arg1=arg2)

MyPy fails with:
example.py:19: error: Incompatible default for argument "arg1" (default has type "Callable[[Optional[float]], float]", argument has type "MyCallback[int, int]")  [assignment]
example.py:19: note: "MyCallback[int, int].__call__" has type "Callable[[NamedArg(Optional[int], 'arg1')], int]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Interestingly if I use callback2 as default it fails the other way around:
example.py:19: error: Incompatible default for argument "arg1" (default has type "Callable[[Optional[int]], int]", argument has type "MyCallback[float, float]")  [assignment]
example.py:19: note: "MyCallback[float, float].__call__" has type "Callable[[NamedArg(Optional[float], 'arg1')], float]"

How would I need to adjust the typing so it's able to properly deduce the result type for the default argument version as well.

I'll note that pyright accepts the code. mypy's error indicates some sort of premature binding of _ResultType to int before you ever call func, but it's not clear how it makes that binding. I thought it might be related to the order in which callback and callback2 are defined, but swapping the order does not change the error message.

Even weirder, mypy still fails if you comment out the definition of callaback2 altogether. I don't know where it's getting the idea that the argument type is MyCallBack[int, int]. (I even tried swapping the order of the constraints in the definitions of the type variables to list float first.)

@chepner: When mypy validates defaults, it doesn't care about what calls to a function actually occur. mypy wants defaults to be valid for every possible parameterization of a generic function.

Ah, OK, it's not picking int specially, it's just the only violation in this case. Adding str to the type variables triggers an additional note about MyCallback[str, str].

The default value has to be valid for any instantiation of MyCallback[_ResultType, _ResultType], so it must be generic as well, not just one specialization.
I'm not sure this is the best workaround, but you can simply cast the default to be an instance of MyCallback.
from typing import cast


def func(
    arg1: MyCallback[_ResultType, _ResultType] = cast(MyCallback, callback),
    arg2: _ResultType | None = None,
) -> _ResultType:
    return arg1(arg1=arg2)


For me this leads to error: Missing type parameters for generic type "MyCallback"  [type-arg] instead

Are you using --strict? That includes --disallow-any-generics, which means you have to use something like MyCallback[Any, Any] explicitly rather than just MyCallback in the cast. (Any is more general than you really want, but as long as you are lying about the type of callback, it hardly matters what lie you are telling, as long as it makes mypy happy :) )

Good catch, I had it set to strict in my pyproject.toml. Using cast(MyCallback[Any, Any], callback) makes it work as expected. The only small downside about lying about the type is that this means that the _ResultType is not derived from the function in this case. So e.g. a: int = func() would pass even though really the return type can't be assigned to int.
Overall still a massive improvement though.

At the very least, you can use float|int in place of Any to match the type variable constraints. You can't use the type variables themselves because they are supposed to capture type information, not provide it.

In my case I have the type hints in a .pyi file anyways, so I had another idea. I can just add two overloads of the function in the type hints: func(arg1: MyCallback[float, float]] = callback, arg2: float | None = None) -> float and func(arg1: MyCallback[_ResultType, _ResultType], arg2: _ResultType | None = None) -> _ResultType.

try this
#return keyword is used to give value to a variable
callback=func(callback)
callback2=func(callback2)
#calling final function to check

it may work work as Quesation is not clear what specific output you needed

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
